# How to Scroll to div after jquery fadein?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my page, I have content and button like this:

```
<div id="1">
  ----some content----
</div>
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="next" id="tut2">
    <a href="#">Next Tutorial &rarr;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="2" style="display:none;">
  ----some content---
</div>
```

Here is my `.js` file:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#tut2").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#1").fadeOut();
    $("#2").fadeIn(3000);
    return false;
   });
  });
```

Fade-In code works perfectly. When the content is faded in, scroll just remains at the bottom. What I want is that page should smooth scroll to `div id=2` or to top after it has faded in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a function to `fadeIn` and it will be run after the animation is completed. For example:

```
$("#2").fadeIn(3000, function(){
    // scroll to #2
    $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#2").offset().top }, 1000);
});
```